# R - Can I delete objects from workspace with index number or condition?

Tags: r, object, indexing, conditional-statements, workspace

I am searching for a possibility to delete objects from my workspace in R by index number.

So for example I`ve got the vectors "a, b, c" and now I want to delete b without using the name. Is is possible to delete objects with a condition or directly with the index number in the workspace?

Thank you!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `remove` with the `list` argument?

Empty workspace:

```
> ls()
character(0)
```

Make some things:

```
> a=1; b=2; c=3
> ls()
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Now to remove the second thing in the working list:

```
> remove(list=ls()[2])
> ls()
[1] "a" "c"
```

The `list` argument will let you remove anything by passing its name as a character string. Its an odd thing to do in a program but if you want to clean up a workspace then yeah. Suppose you have a load of objects called `test_1` up to `test_99999` (illustrated with 4 here):

```
> ls()
[1] "keep_1" "test_1" "test_2" "test_3" "test_4"
> remove(list = ls()[grepl("^test_",ls())])
> ls()
[1] "keep_1"
>
```